# Can't get jquery validate plugin to work with same page update. Validation works, but nothing shows up

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a php file that's suppose to do calculations on 2 inputs and then update a div. I'm trying to get jquery validate the the 2 inputs exists before passing it to my php script (will add other validations later).

Without the validation, it works, but when I use the validation plugin. I can get the validate part to work, but nothing shows up.

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#someForm").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

        form.submit(function() {
            $.post('rev3.php', $('input:text'), function(data) {
                $('.someDiv').html(data);
            });
        });

   }
})

});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="someDiv">

</div>


<form method="post" onsubmit="return false" id="someForm">

First Quarter <input type="text" name="firstQuarter" id="first" class="required"> <br />
Second Quarter <input type="text" name="secondQuarter" id="second" class="required"> <br />

<input type ="submit">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Semi off-topic, start using "required" as an attribute itself instead of using class="required".  Modern browsers will start self-validating it w/o any JavaScript being required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.serialize()` before posting

```
$.post('rev3.php', $('input:text').serialize(), function(data) {
    $('.someDiv').html(data);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, why do you need the `form.submit` part? Try without it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someForm").validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('rev3.php', $('input:text'), function(data) {
                $('.someDiv').html(data);
            });
       }
    })
});
```

Comment: It's got to be something to do with the validation code since without it, everything works

Comment: I got the form.submit part from the validate doc.